# Facebook login page ajax load into jquery ui dialog, on a canvas application

Tags: ajax, facebook, jquery-ui, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a development website on facebook. It's a canvas application built with asp.net mvc3 c#/razor. I'm trying to authenticate the user with the javascript facebook sdk. I'm trying to achieve everything using ajax calls, however, I cannot seem to find a way to ajax load the login(or permissions) dialog into an existing markup id.

```
function dialogLoad(dialogId, url)
{
if (typeof (url) == 'undefined' || typeof (dialogId) == 'undefined')
    return;
$('#' + dialogId).load(url);
var dialog = $('#' + dialogId).dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen:false,
        draggable:false,
        resizable:false,
        closeOnEscape:false
    });
    dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

This is a sample function that should make a facebook login page load in a jquery ui modal dialog. Is there any way to embed the login page into my canvas application? However i try to do this, all i get is a "Go to facebook.com" link instead of my whole app markup, that doesnt even point users in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Also, due to popup blockers and browsers not treating scripts inside iframes well, I'd like to avoid using popups or redirects if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, no popups allowed and no redirects allowed.  Kinda defeats both ways Facebook allow you to log in.

Many developers are using FB.login() (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) from the Facebook Javascript SDK which does either a dialog or a redirect.

Many more are using the login plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login) and have had great results.